# Ajax Requests Chaining/Nesting?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script that uses Ajax. The script will call an API, and then use that data to call the API again, and then based on that a final request to the API a third time.

Currently the Ajax requests are chained, so if response status is 200, it will perform the other Ajax request and if that one is 200 it will do another. So basically nested requests.

They are asynchronous requests. Is this the correct way to do this? I cant help but think its a little messy, and wrong.

Comment: "So basically nested requests."  - erm not really, these sound like synchronous requests (or chained to use your terms) in the scope of your ajax usage.

Comment: I'm using asynchronous requests so the rest of the script is not interrupted, but the 2nd request won't happen until the first is complete. Same with the 3rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ajax request, chaining them with `callbacks` is the right way... its the best way to make sure the second call initializes only after the first one finished successfully.

```
asyncCall1( function(){
   asyncCall2(function(){
      asyncCall3();
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

On javascript-side I would say it's a correct way.

But on API-side instead of multiple requests your api could/should be able to respond with the end-result (or merged results) on the first request, when the following requests are just based on data retrieved by previous requests.